# Initial attempt at node.js automatic redirection

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server

I'm working on a Node.js HTTP server on my iPhone:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var http = require('http');
const port = 8080; 
var readFile = function(name, response) {
    var read = function(err, dat) {
        var rv = null;
        var nope = "./redirect.html";
        if (err) {
            if (name == nope)
                rv = "INTERNET!";
            else {
                rv = readFile(nope, response);
                return;
            }
        }
        else rv = dat;
        response.end(rv);
    }
    fs.readFile(name, "utf-8", read);
}
var client = function(request, response) {
    path = "." + request.url;
    file = readFile(path, response);
}
var server = http.createServer(client);
server.listen(port);
```

**redirect.html**:

```
<script language = "javascript">
window.location = "/index.html";
</script>
Bad request.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     if (err) {
>         if (name == nope)
>             rv = "INTERNET!";
>         else {
>             rv = readFile(nope, response);
>             return;
>         }
>     }
>     else rv = dat;
> ```

Omitting `{}` can easily go sideways especially if you mix it like in the example above. I suggest to always use them.

Even if it's just

```
else { rv = dat; }
```

they greatly helps to see where the `if/else` ends.

> ```
> var nope = "./redirect.html";
> ```

Since you doesn't seem to change it anwhere, I'd make it a constant too.